# load image from pc on a local website css

Tags: css, image, local-files

I am making a website only for usage as a local '.html' file which I can open in Chrome and in that file I am trying to reference an image at

```
"file:///C:\Pictures\BG.png"
```

to make it the document's background, but it won't work. I think I may need something such as:
`src("file:///C:\Pictures\BG.png")`

although that isn't working either what do I need and here is the piece of my css referencing it:

`body{background-color: #000; background-image: 'file:///C:\Pictures\BG.png';}`
(I indented it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep your images in the same folder that you HTML file, this will make easier to work with images. Then you just have to add the property.

```
body { background-image: url(“myimage.jpg”);
```

}

Comment: Thanks that was just what i needed. My program works now :)

Answer (score 1):

Use url ('URL') and forward slash '/'  instead of back slash '\' in the reference , To specify more than one image, separate the URLs with a comma.

```
 urlbackground-image: url("file:///C:/Pictures/BG.png") ;
```

[jsfiddle Here](https://jsfiddle.net/Panther_007/zaju044w/3/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the format `url()` for background images. You should also always use the forward slash in URIs ([reference](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ie/2006/12/06/file-uris-in-windows/)).

```
background-image: url('file:///C:/Pictures/BG.png');
```